WebAssembly : Error "Argument of type 'RegExp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'" in TypeScript when using replaceAll
I’m working on a project using TypeScript, and I’m trying to replace all occurrences of a word (case-insensitive) in a string. Here’s the code I’m using:

const greeting: string = "Hi, World! Hi, world!";
const newGreeting: string = greeting.replaceAll(/hi/gi, "Hello");
console.log(newGreeting);

However, TypeScript throws the following error:

Argument of type 'RegExp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

tsconfig.json
{\
  "extends": "assemblyscript/std/assembly.json",\
  "include": [\
    "./**/*.ts"\
  ],\
}

I know that replaceAll should support regular expressions in plain JavaScript, so I’m not sure if this is a TypeScript-specific issue or if it’s related to WebAssembly (which I’m also using in my project).
My questions are:

Why doesn’t TypeScript allow passing a regular expression to replaceAll like it does in JavaScript?
Is this a limitation of TypeScript or something related to WebAssembly?
What’s the correct way to use replaceAll with regular expressions in TypeScript?

